# Returning cached data from AJAX via deferred callbacks

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have a piece of JS that does an AJAX request to my server, which returns some JSON. It looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    localCache: true,
    cacheTTL: 6,
    url: url
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, something) {
    //Display error message
}).done(function(data) {
    //Do stuff with the data
});
```

Now what I'd like to do is cache the json on the client side using localStorage, so that if the cache is fresh enough, the request is never actually sent, and the cache is used instead. I've been using Paul Irish's ajax-localstorage-cache plugin to do this, but unfortunately it doesn't support deferred callbacks, so I've tried my best to modify it so that it does.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    // Cache it ?
    if ( !Modernizr.localstorage || !options.localCache ) return;

    var hourstl = options.cacheTTL || 5;

    var cacheKey = options.cacheKey || options.url.replace( /jQuery.*/,'' ) + options.type + options.data;

    // if there's a TTL that's expired, flush this item
    var ttl = localStorage.getItem(cacheKey + 'cachettl');
    if ( ttl && ttl < +new Date() ){
        localStorage.removeItem( cacheKey );
        localStorage.removeItem( cacheKey  + 'cachettl' );
        ttl = 'expired';
    }

    var value = localStorage.getItem( cacheKey );
    if ( value ) {
        //In the cache? So get it, apply done callback & abort the XHR request
        // parse back to JSON if we can.
        if ( options.dataType.indexOf( 'json' ) === 0 ) value = JSON.parse( value );

        //Pass value back to the done callback somehow...

        // Abort is broken on JQ 1.5 :(
        jqXHR.abort();
    } else {
        $.Deferred(function(defer) {
            //If it not in the cache, we change the done callback, just put data on localstorage and after that apply the initial callback
            if ( jqXHR.done ) {
                jqXHR.realdone = jqXHR.done;
            }

            jqXHR.done(function(data) {
                var strdata = data;
                if ( options.dataType.indexOf( 'json' ) === 0 ) strdata = JSON.stringify( data );

                // Save the data to localStorage catching exceptions (possibly QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
                try {
                    localStorage.setItem( cacheKey, strdata );
                    // store timestamp
                    if ( ! ttl || ttl === 'expired' ) {
                        localStorage.setItem( cacheKey  + 'cachettl', +new Date() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * hourstl );
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    // Remove any incomplete data that may have been saved before the exception was caught
                    localStorage.removeItem( cacheKey );
                    localStorage.removeItem( cacheKey + 'cachettl' );
                    if ( options.cacheError ) options.cacheError( e, cacheKey, strdata );
                }

                if ( jqXHR.realdone ) jqXHR.realdone( defer.resolve );
            }).fail(defer.reject)
        }).promise(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to figure out how to get the cached value back to the original `done` callback. If I do `jqXHR.abort()`, the `fail` callback is going to be run, and if I don't abort then it's just going to do the request normally.

Am I doing something terribly wrong? If so, what would be a smarter way to do it? If not, how can I get the cached value back to the done callback (or at least get it to the fail callback)?

Comment: You may need to rewire `$.ajax` itself; though, shouldn't the browser cache be good enough?

Comment: For this specific use case, browser caching may be good enough. But we were hoping to use this for other kinds of caching as well, where it might not.

Comment: Are you saying that with the ajax-localstorage-cache plugin installed, `$.ajax()` doesn't return a Promise? If not, then you need to contact the plugin's author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider having a wrapper for your ajax calls. So something like :

```
$.myAjax = function(params,doneCb,failCb){  //doneCb: doneCallback

    var data = getFromLocalStorage(params),

    if( data) {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        dfd.done(doneCb);
    }else{
         dfd = $.ajax(params).done(function(resp){ 
                 // add to localStorage 
                 doneCb && doneCb(resp);
             }).fail(failCb)
   return dfd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/06/ajax-caching-transports-compatible-with-jquery-deferred/

It allows caching of ajax requests with deferred.